# C/C++, negation operator frustration

Tags: c++, c

In the following code segment what will be the result of the function, value of x , value of y

```
{

   unsigned int x=-1;
   int y;
   y = ~0;
   if(x == y)
     printf("same");
   else
     printf("not same");

}
```

Please explain how this works. From my side its answer will be "not same" but its actual answer is "same".

Comment: -1 for an awful, extremely general title.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: -1: hes just spamming the forums with his homework..stop answering them.

Comment: -1 For posting all your homework. Spam

Comment: 7 downvotes and closed as "too localized"? I mean, come on.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is going on, you need to understand how the value of (-1) is stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you hints so that you can figure out the explanation for yourself.

1. Note, x is unsigned int where as y is signed int.
2. Did you learn about bit-wise operators?
3. Alter your program by including the following at the end and see for yourself:

   printf("x = %d, y = %d", x, y);

EDIT: Changed the printf statement to:

```
printf("x = %d, x = %u, y = %d, y = %u, ", x, x, y, y);
```